# Shiny App Error - "Can't access reactive value. Do you need to wrap inside reactive() or observe()?"

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, shiny-server

I am attempting to write a shiny app and the UI is working fine, but when I try to run the server.R code I get an error, and am not sure what to fix to resolve the issue

"Warning: Error in $: Can't access reactive value 'education' outside of reactive consumer.
ℹ Do you need to wrap inside reactive() or observe()?"

Server code:

```
#Load libraries
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

   #Define server logic 
   server <- function(input, output, session) {
   
   salary_filtered <- 
     salarydataUS %>% reactive ({
         filter(input$education %in% education) %>%
         filter(input$underrepresented %in% underrepresented)%>%
         filter(input$teamsize %in% teamsize)%>%
         filter(input$companytype %in% companytype )%>% 
         filter(input$role %in% role) 
     })
   
   #Create an output of filtered data within bargraph
   #Does this need reactive?
   output$bargraph <- renderPlot({
     ggplot(data = salary_filtered, aes(x = input$numberofbins)) +
       geom_bar() + 
       labs(title = "Salary Data",
            x = "Salary",
            y = "") +
       xlim(1000, 600000)
   })
  
   }
```

UI code:

```
#Load libraries
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

#Creation of dropdown options
education <- c('Bachelor\'s Degree', 'College Diploma or Certificate', 'Doctorate (e.g. PhD, EdD)','Master\'s Degree', 'Postgraduate', 'High School Diploma or GED')
role <- c('Junior or Associate UX Researcher','UX Researcher','Senior UX Researcher', 'Principal Researcher', 'UX Research Lead', 'UX Research Manager', 'Director of UX Research', 'VP of UX Research')
companytype <- c('Agency','Government', 'Independent Consultant or Freelance', 'Large Enterprise (example: Walmart, DHL, American Airlines)','Public Tech Company (example: Google, Snowflake, Airbnb)','Tech Startup','Non-Profit')
teamsize <- c('I\'m a team of one!','2 to 4', '5 to 9', '10 to 14', '15 or more')
underrepresented <- c('Yes','No')
numberofbins <- c(3,4,5,6,7,8)

#Creation of UI of Shiny App
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("UX Researcher Salaries"),

#Creation of side panel UI
#Add number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
       selectInput("education", "Highest level of education:", education),
       selectInput("role", "Role:", role),
       radioButtons("underrepresented", "Member of an underrepresented group:", underrepresented),
       radioButtons("teamsize", "Size of UX Research Team:", teamsize),
       radioButtons("companytype", "Type of company", companytype),
       selectInput("numberofbins", "Number of bins:", numberofbins),
    ),
#Creation of mainpanel UI
#Mainpanel not displaying?
    mainPanel(
      #Render bargraph in mainpanel
      plotOutput(outputId = "bargraph", width = "900px")
        )
  )
)
```

I did not have the reactive ({ }) in the server code before, and added that in after the error message, which did not resolve the issue

Comment: You have to put the whole expression in the reactive, i.e. do `salary_filtered <- reactive({ salarydataUS %>% filter(...) })`. Second, to use the value of the reactive in `renderPlot` you have to use `salarydataUS()` instead of `salarydataUS`. Finally, to filter you dataset for the inputs you have to swap the LHS and RHS for `%in%`, i.e. do e.g.`education %in% input$education` instead of `input$education %in% education`.